# Pipe STDERR using IO::Pipe Perl

Tags: perl, pipe

```
my $writer = IO::Pipe->new();
$writer->writer();
print $writer $some_function();
$writer->flush();
$writer->close;
```

What happens if the `some_function` produces some exception or STDERR? Is it written to the `$writer`? If No, How can one achieve that?

Comment: No, you are only printing the result to that handle. /// Exceptions are caught using `eval`. Capturing what would get sent to STDERR is far tricker, but I think Capture::Tiny can help. /// Alternatively, you could assign the pipe to fd 2, making it STDERR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch `$SIG{__WARN__}` and/or `$SIG{__DIE__}`

```
{
    my $writer = IO::Pipe->new();
    $writer->writer();
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print $writer $_[0] };
    local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { print $writer $_[0] };
    print $writer $some_function();
    $writer->flush();
    $writer->close;
}
```

`$SIG{__DIE__}` handler needs a modification depending on how you want to handle critical errors.

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25SIG

Comment: Note that `$SIG{__WARN__}` and `$SIG{__DIE__}` only catch calls to those perl functions, not anything that writes to STDERR directly. Capture::Tiny can be used to capture everything written to STDERR, and [eval or try](http://mvp.kablamo.org/cpan/exceptions/) can be used to capture exceptions, in a much safer way than overriding `$SIG{__DIE__}`.